# Почему так популярна java se?

Tags: java

Я на выходных начал изучать яву, после пары лет программирования на С++. Поставил эклипс и начал писать простые программки, которые через эклипс спокойно запускались. И тут мне стало интересно- что же есть результат работы такого программиста? Ответом оказался .jar файл. 
Тут я радостный создал с помощью эклипса этот файл. Но запустить его я так и не смог, уже третий день бьюсь.

Я не считаю себя гуру, но я как минимум продвинутый пользователь пк. У меня не получилось запустить. 
Запуск этой штуки проблематичен. Значит и распространять такие программы крайне тежело, ведь пользователю придется поставить java машину и если все пройдет гладко он сможет нормально ею пользоваться.

Так почему же очень большая часть вакансий для программистов именно для java?

UPD: при этом не работают и сторонние .jar файлы.

Comment: > Я на выходных начал изучать яву, после
> пары лет программирования на С++.

Поизучайте хотя бы еще пару выходных и после этого и можно будет порассуждать на тему что есть Java и с чем его едят.

> Ответом оказался .jar файл. Тут я
> радостный создал с помощью эклипса
> этот файл. Но запустить его я так и не
> смог, уже третий день бьюсь.

Есть jar как архив, а есть запускаемый jar...

Comment: 2 года программирования для того, чтобы знать, что все что пишется, запускается дабл-кликом на `*.exe`?

Comment: Если не дошли до архивов Java, то и не знаете как его запустить, хотя минута гугления решит проблему.

Для вас:
> java -jar ./application.jar


Answer (score 8, accepted):

Большинство вакансий направленно на Java EE, что подразумевает написание больших корпоративных(серверных) WEB приложений, работающих с БД, выполняющих какую-то бизнес логику и генерирующих веб-страницы.

Comment: Да, и там проблема установки java машины не стоИт...

Comment: Ну да на сервера ее ставят люди с нормальными руками :)

Answer (score 3):

Джава, помимо языка программирования, является огромной платформой для разработки приложений практически любой сложности. Очень развитый и постоянно развивающийся язык. Масса документации, учебников, обучалок, низкий порог вхождения (не считая порога в ООП), полностью Объектно Ориентированный и кроссплатформенный язык.
Плюс в последнее время множество вакансий именно для джава-программистов. 
Короче. Причин Много! :)

Comment: Вы пишете «объектно-ориентированный» с большой буквы, чтобы показать уважение к этой методике программирования?

Comment: - Низкий порог вхождения вряд ли стоит преподносить как плюс.

- Утверждение про кроссплатформенность крайне спорное. Парадигма Write Once Run Anywhere [работает исключительно для серверных приложений](http://java.dzone.com/articles/does-write-once-run-anwhere) — Jason Kincaid nails it: 'write once, run everywhere' has never worked out. It’s a pipe dream.

- Утверждение про вакансии не имеет смысла без сравнения, анализа динамики и приведения статистических данных.

- Минус, короче :)

Comment: Вы сами-то этот текст (где говорится, что работает исключительно для серверных приложений) читали? Первый же комментарий к этому тексту - "All i can say is "Bullsh*t"". Я с этим комментарием полностью согласен.

И чего это ради "низкий порог вхождения вряд ли стоит преподносить как плюс"?

Comment: А с каких это пор "write once run anywhere" отменили? Вот только не надо говорить про platform/OS-dependent UI. С этим и в пределах одной платформы далеко не всегда удаётся без проблем разобраться (в том числе, и с помощью относительно "родного" для данной платформы инструментария), и часто приходится ваять различные отдельные UI для, например, разных версий ОС.

Применительно же к функциональной/алгоритмической части написанного Java кода — пресловутый принцип вполне себе работает. За исключением, разумеется, случаев, когда требуется что-то экзотическое от целевой платформы.

Comment: Так же, не соглашусь с тем, что у Java низкий порог входа. Смотря, что понимать под порогом входа. Сложность начать хоть как-то писать на конкретном языке? Ну так тут и плюсы не шибко сложны: изучив основы синтаксиса за вечер, уже можно сидеть и радостно говнокодить. Если же речь идёт о написании качественного и поддерживаемого кода, то Java не слишком проста. Слишком много нюансов, в том числе и не относящихся непосредственно к языку, нужно знать/помнить/уметь применять. И, несмотря на то, что джавистов относительно немало, качественных разработчиков на ней, на самом деле, не так уж и много.

Comment: А вообще, когда мне говорят, что на Java _нельзя_ сделать годный десктопный софт, я, обычно, тыкаю собеседника носом в продукцию небезызвестной компании JetBrains. :)

Comment: Да вообще, если уж совсем по-детсадовски, то на такой вопрос нужно отвечать так: "Смартфона на Android в жизни не видел?"

Comment: @falstaf

- Заметьте, я не утверждал, что на Java \*нельзя сделать\* хороший кроссплатформенный софт. Я утверждаю лишь то, что Write Once Run Everywhere не работает, как минимум, когда речь заходит о написании качественного UI, следующего гайдлайнам ОС. [Для продуктов JetBrains, с помощью которых вы тыкаете ваших собеседников носом, это тоже верно :)](http://goo.gl/UZFHlq)

- Можете ли вы привести примеры каких-либо известных продуктов, которые используют раздельные UI для различных версий одной и той же ОС? Мне аргумент про "часто приходится ваять" кажется несколько сомнительным.

Answer (score 3):

*Давайте копнём историю.*

Начиналось всё с кофеварок и холодильников. Нужен был язык, который бы с легкостью заработал в микроволновке. Sun увидела эту необходимость, создала подходящий язык.\

Так появилась oak, позже переименованный в java.

А потом оказалось, что язык удобен.

Тем временем начинали создавать телефоны++, так сказать. Те телефоны не сильно то и отличали от микроволновок и холодильников. Всё это называлось просто электроника.

Ну а раз так, почему если java используется для холодильников, не использовать её и на мобилках?

Тогда же мобилки начали поддерживать лёгкие игры, вроде змейки. Но эти игры надо на чём-то писать. Тут отлично вписалась java, имя которой оказалось java me.

Эти мобилки набирали популярность, а вместе с ними и java me.

В тот момент java была уже доступна для компьютеров. А теперь представим обычного продвинутокомпьютерщика, который решил заняться программированием. Он смотрит: ага, есть такой классный язык, как java, на котором можно написать свою змейку и для компа, и для мобилы. Пойду ка выучу.

Вот такой скачёк популярности. Потом java прирослась в интерпрайзе. И т.д. и т.п.

Тем временем sun продалось oracle. Oracle вложило кучу денег и сделало агрессивный JIT, который по скорости может тягаться с плюсами.

Ещё один скачок произошёл благодаря android. Знаю много людей, которые пользовались android смартами, и захотели что-нибудь под него замутить.

А для программирования под android и нужна java. Вот и учили они её.

Вот такими скачками java и выползала на вверх.

Сейчас java попала в список mainstream языков. Люди выбирают между java и с++. Потихоньку им составляет конкуренцию python, c# и др. Когда выбирают java, то выбирают обычно из-за:

1) garbache collector

2) android

3) Слово очень популярное :) (самые обычные люди знают только три названия: c++, java и javascript)

p.s. *Это моё виденье истории. Несогласны? Добро пожаловать в Коментарии.*

Comment: > Люди выбирают между java и с++

Если вы посмотрите на hh.ru, то у видите что люди скорее уже выбирают между Java и C#.

Comment: Увлекательно. Спасибо.

Comment: Прикольно уже 4й раз читать "историю java чужими глазами"

Comment: @zenith скинте плиз первые 3 места, где вы читали. Будет как раз в тему

Comment: Млин, вот так и происходит переписывание истории. Все было не так - совсем не так!

Comment: @Barmaley спасибо за минус). Можно вопрос - что именно не так? И ещё - это не переписывание истории, её ещё никто не написал.

Comment: @Barmaley, ну, все же не совсем *не так*. Началось-то с "пылесосов" (точнее с пульта для телевизора).

А вот следующий (весьма значимый) этап с браузерами почти не освещен. 

И "энтерпрайз" (видимо основной двигатель популярности Java) т.е. серверная часть клиент-серверных WEB-приложений упомянут как-то вскользь.

--

Конечно, мой список весьма не полон, но утверждение

        совсем не так!

требует развернутого ответа!

Comment: @danpetruk в порядке приобретения книг:

 1. [И.Хабибулин "Java 7"][1]
 2. [Керк Скотт "Java для студента][3]
 3. [Кэти Сьерра, Берт Бейтс "Изучаем Java"][2]

P.s. Номер два оказался самый неудачный выбор. Не понравился стиль автора и скупость на упражнения.  
Хабибулин пошёл легко, хотя многие вещи всё равно пришлось понимать самому.  
А вот про последний только положительные впечатления, хоте ещё не дочитал.

  [1]: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7328622/
  [2]: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7821666/
  [3]: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/21012612/

Comment: @danpetruk что же ты не сказал, что java, которая вертится на андройде это не та православная java к которой мы привыкли … эх ты … историк блин …